# How can I use the HTML download attribute with a list?

Tags: javascript, html, list, download, attributes

I'm trying to use the download attribute to automatically download generated PDFs with unique links and have the downloaded file have a name based on an identifier from the link (the last several digits).

I'm using this download attribute I found when Googling the issue.

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="w3logo">
```

But I'm having trouble trying to reconcile it with a list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Download PDF</button>

<script>

var links = ['LINK1','LINK2','LINK3','LINK4','LINK5'];

function myFunction() 
{
links.forEach(function(element))
    {
        var ID = element.substring(5);
    }
};

</script>

<a href=element download=ID> 

</body>
</html>
```

I'm suspecting that it's this part that is causing the issue:

```
<a href=element download=ID>
```

But I'm not too familiar with html/javascript. Thank you for the help.

Comment: unclear how that anchor corresponds with that array

Comment: all the 'download' attribute does is say that the linked file should be downloaded, not opened in the browser.  --Edit: You can also specify a different default save as filename -- For what you are trying to do, you need an app engine like .net or php

Comment: My apologies for being unclear, this is new to me too in terms of relaying my problems. So I do want to use the download attribute and I do want the linked file be downloaded. I just want the download attribute to be used kind of like a loop where it goes through the links, downloads it, and give it a unique name based on the last digits in its name.